# how to convert list into tuple in python , all elements of list should be in int?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input, tuples

use proper example for clarification

I need solution through code
list
tuple
w

list should be changed in tuple int first then convert into tuple

Comment: Can you provide some code? What have you already tried and what went wrong?

Comment: At least provide data for example.

Answer (score 1):

```py
_list = [1, 2, 3, "hello", "world"]
_tuple = tuple(_list)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking care to _not_ alias important builtin names, such as `tuple`. That's great. But please note that leading underscore is conventionally used for identifiers that are private to a module or class, identifiers that are not exported as part of a public API. The [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) style guide advises you to use trailing underscore (`tuple_`) in a situation like we find in this SO question. (And thank you for not using `l`, on which PEP-8 _also_ has some [advice](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) to offer.)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
l_int = [int(i) for i in l] # Convert everything to int one by one and save in new list to later convert to tuple

t = tuple(l_int)
```

Like this?